# Angular model is not being updated on animate complete callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following HTML is included in my ng-controller div

```
<div id="cards-slider">
    <div ng-repeat="card in cards">
        <a href="#" title="Title" ng-click="toggleFavorite(card)">
        <i class="icon-star" ng-class="card.isFavorite ? 'favorite' : ''"></i>
    </a>
        <div class="card-holder ng-cloak">
            <img src="{{ card.imageSrc }}" />
        <p><a href="#">{{ card.programName }}</a></p>                       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="next ng-cloak" ng-show="cartsTotal > limit && isNotLastPage" ng-click="getNextCards()"></a>
```

When I click getNextCards I will execute a HTTP request to get more cards. On success callback I wanted to start an jQuery animation (code below) and only after being completed I wanted to updated my cards model. But this approach doesn't work, keeping the same cards. Do you have any workaround? Thanks

```
$( "#cards-slider" ).animate({
    left: "-=500",
}, 100, function() {
    $scope.cards        =   data.elements;
    $scope.cartsTotal   =   data.total;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the jquery ajax and animate functions are outside [angular's digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24digest). You'll need to force a digest manually. Try this:

```
$( "#cards-slider" ).animate({
    left: "-=500",
}, 100, function() {
    $scope.cards        =   data.elements;
    $scope.cartsTotal   =   data.total;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) { // if digest is not already running
        $scope.apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: It only worked like this $scope.$apply()! But thks, now I have what I want ;)